# Proving a Tautology Formally

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I wish to prove:
$(\neg p\leftrightarrow q)\leftrightarrow\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)$

Comment: The question is tagged (formal-proofs). What are your inference rules?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to prove by truth table:

```
~ = NOT, <=> = iff
p  q  ~p<=>q  ~(p<=>q)
T  T     F        F
T  F     T        T
F  T     T        T
F  F     F        F
```

## Otherwise

We define $\Leftrightarrow$ to be $\neg(x\oplus y)$, where $\oplus$ is $(x\vee y)\wedge \neg(x\wedge y)$.
$$\begin{align*}(\neg p\Leftrightarrow q)&\leftrightarrow \neg(p\Leftrightarrow q)&&\text{given}\\
&\leftrightarrow\neg(\neg(p\oplus q))&&\text{by definition}\\
&\leftrightarrow p\oplus q&&\text{double negation=positive}\
\end{align*}$$
and 
$$\begin{align*}(\neg p\Leftrightarrow q)&\leftrightarrow \neg(p\Leftrightarrow q)&&\text{given}\\
\neg(\neg p\oplus q)&\leftrightarrow&&\text{by definition}\\
p\oplus q&\leftrightarrow &&\text{double negation=positive}\
\end{align*}$$
From this, $p\oplus q\leftrightarrow p\oplus q$, therefore, $(\neg p\Leftrightarrow q)\leftrightarrow \neg(p\Leftrightarrow q) \>\>\blacksquare.$